# consume REST service using apigee

Tags: rest, apex-code, apigee

I'm new to using REST services and I'm using apigee.com to test GET and POST requests for my REST service.

My question is, how can I test my POST request by passing parameters to create the new record?

I can run my GET request successfully and I get back a JSON response with the records requested.

When I try my post request, I'm getting an error:

```
"message": "Content-Type header specified in HTTP request is not supported: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
"errorCode": "UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE"
```

Here is my class method:

```
@HttpPost
global static Merchandise createMerchandise(String name, String description, Double price, Integer totalInventory) {
    System.Debug('POST /merchandise/*');

    Merchandise__c merchandise = new Merchandise__c();
    merchandise.Name = name;
    merchandise.Description__c = description;
    merchandise.Price__c = price;
    merchandise.Total_Inventory__c = totalInventory;

    insert merchandise;

    Merchandise merch = castToMerchandise(merchandise);

    return merch;
}
```

How do I pass the parameters in the URL and how do I specify the correct content type using the agigee console to test my service?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look in to the format that you are having your Rest service accept and add "x-www-form-urlencoded" if you are going to continue using it to send payloads to the URL.

You specify the Content-Type under the Headers tab in the Apigee console, you just need to look in to what the Content-Type the server accepts.

To pass parameters in the url you just attach `?` to the end of the Url and put the variable names and values. These are usually called [queryStrings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)
like so:

www.example.com?name=Dman100&Rep=104.

This example will pass to variables name and Rep. When passing variables in the URL you must be careful to html url encode the variables and their values.

For Posts you send the content in the payload/body. In whatever format is necessary.

Comment: I can't seem to add any paramaters/values to the Header, Template or Body in the apigee console for my REST Service.  If I use the GET Request and run: `https://c16.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account/001f0000007qcD5` I get a successful response.  But, if I try and run a POST Request, I can't enter any parameters into the Body, Header or Template?

Comment: Are you using the generic api console for apigee?

Comment: I'm able to enter body, header, etc. What function are you trying to call?

Comment: I'm trying to call a POST to test my REST Service to verify it creates the account record.  I have successfully tested the GET Request, which returns the correct records.  But, when I try to test the POST, I cannot enter any parameters in the Header, Template and Body, which I thought I should be able to do like: `{ "name" : "Test" }` etc...This is probably user error on my part as I'm new to REST and also using the apigee console.

Comment: Yeah I understand the GET part. Get doesn't require some things that POST does so it's simple. Since this is your own REST service why aren't you using [generic console](https://apigee.com/console/others)? This will allow you to specify where you want to send your request to and the details with it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34470/discussion-between-dman100-and-clyde-byrd-iii)